# Выравнивание маркеров на один уровень, при разном меж строчном интервале

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы маркеры у списка были на одном уровне

```css
.sample-reports__list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 68px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sample-reports__list li { 
    position: relative;
    font: 14px "Roboto_Light", sans-serif;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 27px; 
}
.sample-reports__list li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -25px;
    content: "";
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #f57b2e;
}
.sample-reports__list--normal {
    line-height: normal !important;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sample-reports__list">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба"</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для </li>
  <li>тексттексттекст тексттексттексттекст тексттекст</li>
  <li>текст тексттексттекст</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для 
  </li><li>текст</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для </li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">
 Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данной метки списка универсально можно сделать так:

```css
.sample-reports__list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 68px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sample-reports__list li { 
    position: relative;
    font: 14px "Roboto_Light", sans-serif;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 27px; 
}
.sample-reports__list li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -25px;
    content: "";
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #f57b2e;
}
.sample-reports__list--normal {
    line-height: normal !important;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

/* Нужные стили */
.sample-reports__list li:before {
  content: '■';
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #f57b2e;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sample-reports__list">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба"</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для </li>
  <li>тексттексттекст тексттексттексттекст тексттекст</li>
  <li>текст тексттексттекст</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для 
  </li><li>текст</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для </li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">
 Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.sample-reports__list--normal:before {    
    top: 5px;
}
```

```css
.sample-reports__list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 68px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sample-reports__list li { 
    position: relative;
    font: 14px "Roboto_Light", sans-serif;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 27px; 
}
.sample-reports__list li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -25px;
    content: "";
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #f57b2e;
}
.sample-reports__list li.sample-reports__list--normal {
    line-height: normal !important;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
.sample-reports__list li.sample-reports__list--normal:before {    
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sample-reports__list">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба"</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для </li>
  <li>тексттексттекст тексттексттексттекст тексттекст</li>
  <li>текст тексттексттекст</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для 
  </li><li>текст</li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для </li>
  <li class="sample-reports__list--normal">
 Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для 
  </li>
</ul>
```